# vuejs vue-router Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

Hi guys I am using vuejs and laravel to redirect url, unfortunately I keep on getting the error 'Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'.

Here is the code:

```
edit(animal){

   this.$route.router.push({path: '/api/animals/' + animal.id + '/edit'})

    },
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation? [_"Note: Inside of a Vue instance, you have access to the router instance as `$router`. You can therefore call `this.$router.push`"_](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys.
This way solved the issue.

```
 edit(animal){

 this.$router.push({path: '/api/animals/' + animal.id + '/edit'})

},
```